# How to sign points on graphics in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I need your help in pyqtgraph library.

This is what I need:

[image: This is what i need]

It is my code. I plot `pg.ScatterPlotItem`.

```
w1 = view.addPlot()
w1.setXRange(0, 10)
w1.setYRange(6, 7)
s1 = pg.ScatterPlotItem(size=3, pen=pg.mkPen(None), brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 255, 255, 255))
dur1 = np.arange(0.1, 5, 2)
data = np.arange(0.1, 5, 2)
s1.setData(x= dur1, y = data) # text = ['A1','A2','A3']
w1.addItem(s1 )
```

Comment: whats wrong with it

Comment: Nothing, how to sign points on my graphics. it is my question)

Comment: Do you mean that in the plot appears A_n according to the case associated with each point as its image shows?

Comment: In general yes.